# Automatically copy files without overwriting, but creating numbered ones instead

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, xcopy, robocopy

I need to copy files at a regular interval, eg once an hour so I tried setting up an xcopy batch saying it should copy the files it needs to copy to another folder. Now when it copies, it overwrites the files which is not what it is supposed to do.

When a file is copied, it should create a new file instead, named something like File.txt, File-COPY1.txt, File-COPY2.txt or something like that.

Any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create individual files for each run by simply adding a time stamp to the file name. Something like this:

```
XCOPY "File.txt" "[TargetDir]\File1_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.txt"
```

This resolves to a file name that reads as `File1_11_30_05.txt` given that the copy operation takes place at 11:30:05. The `%time:~0,2%` part extracts 2 digits from the time string stored in the variable `%time%`.

In addition you could also add the date in the same fashion. You can use the variable `%date%`  for this purpose.

If you really need a pattern like `File-COPY1.txt`, `File-COPY2.txt` etc. This needs a bit more work.  Tell us if the time stamp approach is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

This batch takes the name of two directories, either relative or explicit, and copies all the files in the first directory to the second directory, but adding a -# between the filename and extension (where # is the number of copies of the file in the second directory). So if there is only one file (`MISC.txt`) copied from dir1 into dir2, but it's been copied 4 times, dir2 will contain 4 files: (`MISC-1.txt` `MISC-2.txt` `MISC-3.txt` and `MISC-4.txt`)

To use `zcopy.bat` call it like this `zcopy fromDir toDir`

`zcopy.bat`

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
if "%1"=="/?" type %~dpnx0 & goto :eof
if "%2"=="" goto :eof
if not exist %2 md %2
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (%1\*.*) do (
  set this=
  set count=1
  if "%%~xx"=="" (
    set backstop=.
  ) else (
    set backstop=
  )
  for /f %%y in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:n "%2\%%~nx-*%%~xx!backstop!" 2^>nul') do ( 
    set this=%%~nxy
  )
  if not "!this!"=="" (
    set count=!this:%%~nx-=!
    if "%%~xx"=="" (
      set /a count=!count!+1
    ) else (
      set /a count=!count:%%~xx=! + 1
    )
  )
  set target=%%~nx-!count!%%~xx
  echo copy "%%x" "%2\!target!"
  copy "%%x" "%2\!target!" > nul 2>&1
)
```

If the directory `%2` does not exist, the above code will create it.

Comment: Not trying to sound stupid or something, but do I have to replace %1 with the starting directory and %2 with the destination? And what should I put in the other parameters? Thanks :)

Comment: @user1688322 - No, you don't need to edit the code. %1, %2 %3 etc. are built-in place-holders for arguments passed to your batch file. So if you enter `zcopy fromDir toDir` then `%1` == `fromDir` and `%2` == `toDir` while `%3` is left blank.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to make a backup of files on a daily basis.

```
    set aa=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~12,2%
    copy filename.txt c:\backupfolder\filename%aa%.txt
```

Hope that helps some.
Scott....

Answer (score 0):

iterates the file name i.e. each time give some new name. you can simply append numerical numbers. 
**use one counter, each time increment it& incremented counter concatenates with fileName**